# msg.exe sent to all users with response function

Tags: powershell, server, msg

I am trying to not log users off if they are still working by sending a msg and allowing the users to select "Yes" or "No".  I am able to do this via wscript, but haven't found a way to do it via msg.  The reason I need to use msg is because it has to go to all users on the server.

```
$prompt = new-object -comobject wscript.shell 
$answer = $prompt.popup("Are you still working?  The shutdown was triggered and this server will shut down.  This message will expire in 30 seconds`n",30,"Idle Shutdown Triggered",0x4 + 0x20 + 0x1000)              
if($answer -eq 6) {"Yes You ARE!"}
if($answer -eq 7) {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'some api to stop the shutdown'-Method POST -Body $postParams}
if($answer -eq -1) {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'some api to stop the shutdown'-Method POST -Body $postParams}
```

I have tested `msg * /W "Message"` and the prompt worked, but I need to execute the api url if no response or they say "No"

Comment: there's plenty of alternatives if you're not specifically looking for msg.exe, such as [this](https://ss64.com/ps/messagebox.html).

Comment: @AbrahamZinala would this take into account all logged in users?  This is a remote execution, so this script isn't local to the server.  This is why msg works

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can't return output from Msg.exe. If it's a single user per system, you can run it under their context using scheduled tasks.